# ES6 classes dependencies injection in AngularJS 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, es6-class

I'm writing an AngularJS (v1) application using ES6 classes, and I need to inject the `$http` service in all the scope of my class.

I've found 2 approach to do so :

```
// 1) Use 'this'
// =====================
class HelloWorld {
    constructor($http) {
        this.$http = $http;
    }

    getTest() {
        this.$http.get('http://api.myjson.com')
                  .then(res => console.log(res))
    }
}

// 2) Use WeakMap
// =====================
const HTTP = new WeakMap();

class HelloWorld {
    constructor($http) {
        HTTP.set(this, $http);
    }

    getTest() {
        HTTP.get(this)
            .get('http://api.myjson.com')
            .then(res => console.log(res))
    }
}
```

I don't really see what's the benefits to use a WeakMap here (in fact, I'm not really sure to understand how WeakMap works, maybe that's the point ^^ )

Also, do you know any other more elegant solutions to accomplish this ? (I though maybe with ES2016 Decorators/Annotation)

Thanks.

Comment: See [ToddMoto: AngularJS ES6 Style Guide - Classes for Service](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide#classes-for-service).

Comment: Okay, so using `this` seems to be the good solution. Granted!
Thanks for the guide. Looks like it's an awesome resource!